# Trying to export PDF using Java, Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

My intention is to export a list to PDF. The list originally came from an XML file, then sorted and put into a list.

I am creating a web interface that would instantiate the export to PDF function. The code below allows a PDF to be created however when I open the PDF, it says PDF failed to load.

I think my issue is in the **pdfAsc function** but I am not sure. Would it help if I made it into a table? If so, can anyone guide me to a tutorial on how to create tables with itext library that allows for this type of list?

This is my code:

```
package com.wywm.superconsole.controller;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.wywm.superconsole.Functions.PDF;
import com.wywm.superconsole.Functions.Troops;
import com.wywm.superconsole.user.User;
import com.wywm.superconsole.user.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
@Controller
public class AppController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@GetMapping("")
public String viewHomePage() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/index")
public String logoutPage() {return "index";}

@GetMapping("/menu")
public String menuPage() {return "menu";}

@GetMapping("/register")
public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());

    return "signup_form";
}

@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegister(User user) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

    userRepo.save(user);

    return "menu";
}

@GetMapping("/users")
public String listUsers(Model model) {
    List<User> listUsers = userRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);

    return "users";
}
// Reads data from an XML file and copys the data to a List (List<User>
// userList).
public  List<Troops> getTroops() {
    List<Troops> TroopList = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        // File path to the XML file.
        Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\amani\\OneDrive\\WYWM\\Java\\Capstone 
1\\dataset.xml");
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(filePath.toAbsolutePath()));

        if (file.exists()) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = 
documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = 
documentBuilder.parse(String.valueOf(filePath.toAbsolutePath()));
            // Reads the XML tagName of full_name and id.
            NodeList[] user = { document.getElementsByTagName("full_name"), 
document.getElementsByTagName("id") };

            for (int i = 0; i < user[0].getLength(); i++) {

                String fullName = user[0].item(i).getTextContent();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(user[1].item(i).getTextContent());
                Troops newTroop = new Troops(fullName, id);
                TroopList.add(newTroop);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // Returns the TroopList with data from the XML file.
    return TroopList;

}
@RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listAsc(Model model) {
    List<Troops> ascList = getNumAsc();
    model.addAttribute("AscList", ascList);
    return "numasc";
}


public List<Troops> getNumAsc( ) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());
    return ascList;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/numdesc", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public  List<Troops> getNumDes() {
    List<Troops> desList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    desList.addAll(getTroops());
    desList.sort((u1, u2) -> u2.getId() - u1.getId());
    return desList;
}


public void pdfAsc(HttpServletResponse response) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    try {
        // Create Document instance.
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

        // Create OutputStream instance.
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("C:\\Users\\amani\\OneDrive\\WYWM\\Java\\Capstone 
1\\asc.pdf"));


        // Create PDFWriter instance.
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

        // Open the document.
        document.open();

        // Create asc List
        com.itextpdf.text.List ascList = new 
com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.ORDERED);
        ascList.add(new ListItem(String.valueOf((getNumAsc()))));


        // Add casdList to the pdf.
        document.add(ascList);

        // Close document and outputStream.
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();

        System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "PDF created successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




private void exportToPDFAsc(HttpServletResponse response, List<Troops> players) throws 
DocumentException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM_HH-mm");
    String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=Ascending List of Troops" + 
currentDateTime + ".pdf";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    List<Troops> listAscTroops = getNumAsc();

    PDF PdfAsc = new DataPDFExporter(listAscTroops);
    PdfAsc.export(response);
}

@GetMapping ("/pdfasc")
public void exportToPDFASC(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, 
DocumentException {
    exportToPDFAsc(response, getNumAsc());
}

private class DataPDFExporter extends PDF {
    public DataPDFExporter(List<Troops> Troops) {
        this.Troops = Troops;
    }
}
@GetMapping("/ExportToPDFDesc")
public void pdfDesc() {

    try {
        // Create Document instance.
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

        // Create OutputStream instance.
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("C:\\Users\\amani\\OneDrive\\WYWM\\Java\\Capstone 
1\\desc.pdf"));

        // Create PDFWriter instance.
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

        // Open the document.
        document.open();

        // Create reverseOrder list.
        com.itextpdf.text.List descList = new com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.ORDERED);
        descList.add(new ListItem(String.valueOf((getNumDes()))));
        Collections.reverseOrder();

        // Add descList.
        document.add(descList);
        // document.add(unorderedList);

        // Close document and outputStream.
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();

        System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "PDF created successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the response.getOutputStream() to the OutputStream instance that you created in the **pdfAsc** method

> Original Code

```
// Create PDFWriter instance.
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
```

> Alternative Code

```
// Create PDFWriter instance.
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
```